# Equivalent of constraint layout 0dp

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I've been trying to achieve the following layout with compose:

[image]

For this, I've created the composable:

```kotlin
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun element() {
    ConstraintLayout(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        val (checkbox, title, icon) = createRefs()

        Text(
            text = "This would be some text",
            style = TextStyle(
                color = Color.Black,
                fontSize = 18.sp,
            ),
            modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(title) {
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                start.linkTo(checkbox.end)
                end.linkTo(icon.start)
            },
        )

        Checkbox(
            checked = false,
            modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(checkbox) {
                top.linkTo(title.top)
                bottom.linkTo(title.bottom)
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
            },
            onCheckedChange = {},
        )

        Icon(
            asset = Icons.Filled.Close,
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(icon) {
                    top.linkTo(title.top)
                    bottom.linkTo(title.bottom)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                }
        )
    }
}
```

However, the text composable does not fill the entire space and the UI looks like:
[image]

I've tried adding modifiers to the `Text` composable like `Modifier..fillMaxWidth()`, but this results in:

[image]

I've tried also to use a constraint set with a horizontal chain, but to no avail. I know that removing `end.linkTo(icon.start)` would look like this is achievable, but when the text would be really long it would overlap with the delete icon.

What am I missing here? How do I achieve the same result as in the view system when we say the `TextView`'s width is `0dp`?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Use [`Dimension.fillToConstraints`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/Dimension#filltoconstraints):

> A Dimension that spreads to match constraints. Links should be
> specified from both sides corresponding to this dimension, in order
> for this to work.

Add this line to your `Text` modifier:

```
width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
```

So it becomes:

```
Text(
    text = "This would be some text",
    style = TextStyle(
        color = Color.Black,
        fontSize = 18.sp,
    ),
    modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(title) {
        top.linkTo(parent.top)
        bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
        start.linkTo(checkbox.end)
        end.linkTo(icon.start)
        width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
    },
)
```

Comment: Very nice! One follow up question, do you have a link where this is explained? thanks!

Comment: It's there in a [compose codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-layouts/#8) under the section "Customizing dimensions"

Comment: you need the dependency `implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.0-rc02"` see https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/constraintlayout#0

Comment: @SaurabhThorat is there any way to add double condition, for instance : width = Dimension.fillToConstraints when the text is small and width = Dimension.wrapContent when the text is large?

Comment: this does not work now

Comment: I cant find the constrainAs in the version"androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.1". does anybody know if it has been replaced with something else?

Comment: It's perfectly!